# InfoPath form tabbing out of form fields and not into controls

Tags: infopath

I have a form on infopath that when tabbing through, tends to go off into sections outside the form, where there is no data.  It also will not tab into controls, such as radio buttons and drop-down menus.  Has anyone had this problem?  The tabbing order has all been set to 0, so I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the tab order to 0 on all items is what is probably causing the issue.  Without that set, there is no direction to specify which field to goto next.  If you want a control skipped in the tab index, you can use -1.  See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/change-the-default-tab-order-for-controls-HP001098468.aspx for more details on tab ordering.

Comment: I understand however it has about 57 controls already.  The tab order does go in order with all tabs set at 0, but not with radio buttons, the focus wont seem to ever go into.  Also, say with three dropdown menus and then a text box that follows, when tabbing to the first dropdown menu, you are able to focus in, select an answer, but then to leave, the focus jumps to the text box, instead of the next drop down.  I could see this being fixed by numerically setting tabs, but with the radio buttons even if tab is out of order, it refuses to enter into radio buttons at all.   Thanks for your help.